# How reload Twig cache in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a application which is developed in PHP using the Symfony 2 framework. I have changed a HTML file, but the change is not reflecting when I refresh the page.

1. I restarted the server. No luck.
2. I tried to remove the Twig folder from the `/protected/cache/` page itself. This is not loading.

How can I reload the Twig cache?

Notes:

- I am using tomcat server to deploy.
- I don’t have the Symfony 2 command line configured on the server.
- I am new to PHP.

Comment: Do you have FTP access to the server?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The most simple way, type the command :

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

The point is: all files in `app/cache/` can be removed freely, they are regenerated when needed.

If you really want to clear only twig cache :

```
rm -rf app/cache/<environment>/twig
```

Replace `<environment>` by `dev`, `prod`, or `test` according to your requirements.

Comment: You should also delete templates.php if you have overwritten other bundle templates and want it to find new ones.

Answer (score 40):

When creating a new Twig_Environment instance, you can pass an array of options as the constructor second argument. One of them is `auto_reload`. When developing with Twig, it's useful to recompile the template whenever the source code changes. If you don't provide a value for the `auto_reload` option, it will be determined automatically based on the `debug` value.

Set `auto_reload` to be `true`:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('auto_reload' => true));
```

Twig's documentation for developers:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options

Answer (score 14):

I had a similar problem, but deleting the cache-folder did not have any impact on my template and I don't know why. What seems to solve my problem now is the following code in my config_dev.yml:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

Maybe this is also a solution for you, so that you don't need to use the command all the time.

References:

[TwigBundle Configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html)

[Twig Environment Options](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options)

Comment: well good idea
I have another case where twig does not seem to recompile always, the auto_reload is ignored sometimes. So for now I go without cache.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using opcache/other similar caching, deleting twig's cache folder won't refresh templates as twig cache consist of only .php files.
You need to delete twig's cache folder + execute php file which contains:

opcache_reset();

Answer (score 4):

You have to do some changes in app.php file located in web folder.

Change:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

and clear the cache if you want.

Comment: I couldn't find what does this second parameter mean exactly. Do you have a clue?

Comment: @KrzysztofPrzygoda probably the second parameter is the value of the first parameter (e.g., set 'prod' to false, set 'prod' to true).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Symfony console to clear cache
`./bin/console cache:clear`

Comment: for windows OS run "php ./bin/console cache:clear"  in root folder

Answer (score 1):

you can add a function like this :

```
public function renderView($view, array $parameters = array())
{
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem($this->container->getParameter("template_path"));
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array('auto_reload' => true,
        'cache' => false
    ));

    /////////////////////add a translate filter/////////////////////// 
    $getTextdomain = new \Twig_SimpleFilter('trans',function ($string){
        return $this->container->get('translator')->trans($string);
    });

    $twig->addFilter($getTextdomain);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    ///////////////////////////Add an extension twig//////////////////
    $twig->addExtension(new Extension());
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return $twig->render($view, $parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OPcache make sure to comment out `opcache.validate_timestamps=0` in dev environment.