# Symfony: Twig values remain the same

Tags: php, symfony, caching, twig

I have a problem with values from twigs that does not change. 
In a twig I use the values of some parameters form a yml file that is imported.
If the content from the imported file is changed, the values from the twig remain the same.

Why does twig values remain cached? Or how can I clear only twig caches? 
I don't want to clear all cache every time and neither set cache value to false for twig.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386925/how-reload-twig-cache-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `prod` environment, twig templates are cached and you will need to clear the 
twig cache to see changes.

You can clear twig cache with this command :

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

or:

```
rm -rf app/cache/prod/twig
```

When you use `dev` environment, twig templates will be automatically recompiled when changes are made to it.

Note that this does not remove APC cache.

Here is the doc [about twig template caching](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#twig-template-caching).