# Symfony2 authentication roles not updating in TWIG template

Tags: symfony, caching, twig

**UPDATE: it seems it isn't the twig cache, but twig isn't recognising the newly added ROLE (in production mode) until after a few minutes.**

I have a twig template in a Symfony2 application which checks a user's roles like so:

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_PLATINUM_MEMBER') %}
    <span>YOU ARE A PLATINUM MEMBER</span>
{% elseif is_granted('ROLE_MEMBER') %}
    <span>YOU ARE A NORMAL MEMBER</span>
{% endif %}
```

The role is upgraded after a return from PayPal (successful payment).

However, twig still shows `YOU ARE A NORMAL MEMBER` (only in production mode).
If the user logs out and back in again, the correct role is shown.

This leads me to think it is the twig cache. I think it isn't Symfony, because if I navigate to a page which contains the same code as above (that I did not visit before going to PayPal), then `YOU ARE A PLATINUM MEMBER` is shown.

I have looked [at this answer for flushing the twig cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386925/how-reload-twig-cache-in-symfony2), but setting:

```
twig:
    cache: false
```

Would be bad for production mode.

Is there any way of flushing this programatically?
I found [this `flush` command](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/flush.html) but am not completely sure whether it is what I need or not.

Maybe I need to use some code which fetches the user and checks the roles instead of just checking roles?

Comment: I think that this has nothing to do with twig caching. Try reloading the user. And yes, turning off the twig cache is not a good idea.

Comment: If it isn't a twig thing, then I'm not sure why twig templates that I didn't previously load before going to paypal, show the correct elevated `ROLE`!

Comment: Its not Twig related, when you add role to user, you can refresh user in security content: $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->setUser($user);

Comment: doesn't seem to work, the twig templates that were loaded before the role was changed (before returning from paypal) are still showing a 'normal member'

Comment: I still have to log out and back in for them to show the new role (again, pages which weren't loaded before returning from paypal are showing the new role correctly, so the security context knows the change has been made)

Comment: Still haven't solved this, I don't think it is the twig cache, but there is also something else getting in the way (@malcolm your comment was helpful but not the whole solution) which is causing only the twig template visited before going to paypal to not show the newly added role. It also seems to be time based, because if I refresh nothing happens, but if I wait a few minutes and then refresh, then it shows.

Comment: One thing left to try: `$this->get('session')->migrate();`

Comment: or `$this->get('session')->invalidate();`

Comment: ah amazing `$this->get('session')->migrate();` worked!

Comment: @malcolm if you put this with a small explanation into an answer, I will award the bounty to you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I stated in comment, there is nothing related to Twig cache.
When you update database with new role, the session still keep the old roles assigned when user logged in. The easiest solution is to refresh session by regenerating session ID:

```
$this->get('session')->migrate();
```

Another approach is to force user to reauthenticate:

```
$token->setAuthenticated(false);
```

For example get security user, add role, save to db and reauthenticate:

```
...
$token = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
$user = $token->getUser();
$user->addRole('ROLE_PLATINUM_MEMBER');
$dm->flush();
$token->setAuthenticated(false);
```

That way we have fresh user session with all roles saved before to database.

```
//If we check for user role:
$this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_PLATINUM_MEMBER');
//This return true.
```

Comment: thanks malcolm, can't award bounty for 19 hours so will do it then!

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @malcolm @timhc22 It is very interesting which session storage do you use? Cause for basic `NativeSessionStorage` should not work - on migration it copies data of the previous session with the outdated `UsernamePasswordToken`. At least the code what I see and my tests say so. I suggest to count `$token->setAuthenticated(false);` as the reliable solution of your problem but not the migration.

Comment: I use mongodb, in my case new session document is made, but you'r right, I not tested it on default Symfony installation, my bad.

Comment: @malcolm There is the issue for the problem https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12025 It will be useful for the world I guess if you will add the link to your answer:)