# Webserver uses old non existing files to render website

Tags: javascript, php, webserver, silex, filezilla

I've got my files uploaded to my website. When I view the website, the online html looks like this:
[image]

However, that's definitely not the file that is online. I've tried to update it many times. However, it still renders a file that I was using a long time ago. I tried to removes my cache and cookies. But for some weird reason, it still manages to use an old deleted file... why is that?

The html that should be online looks like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}

<div id="preloader"></div>

<div id="s1" class="hero">
    <div id="menu_block" name="menu_block" class="menu_block right">
        <nav class="nav_block">
            <a href="#s1">Home</a>
            <a href="#s2">About</a>
            <a href="#s3">Projects</a>
            <a href="#s4">Skills</a>
            <a href="#s5">Resume</a>
            <a href="#s6">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="container vertical center">
        <div class="title white">
            Lex de Willigen
        </div>
        <div class="subtitle white">
            DEVELOPER
        </div>
        <div class="subsubtitle">
            <i>Hello, my name is Lex and I'm <br>
            a developer from the Netherlands!</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s2" class="section">
    <div class="container vertical center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="container vertical center" style="">
        <h2 style="font-weight: 900; font-family: arial; color: black;">
            WHO AM I?
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="container vertical center" style="">
        <p>
            <b>Hi!</b> My name is Lex. 
            <h3 class="animate">And I'm developer</h3>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s3" class="section">
    <div class="container vertical center" style="">
        <h2>
            Projects
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s4" class="section">
    <div class="container vertical center" style="">
        <h2>
            Skills
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s5" class="section">
    <div class="container vertical center" style="">
        <h2>
            Resume
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="s6" class="section">
    <div class="container vertical center" style="width: 50%;">
        <h2>
            Contact
        </h2>

        {% if form is defined %}
            <form action="" method="post">
                {{ form_widget(form) }}
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Some extra details:

1. I'm using the Silex framework
2. For some reason, I never get my javascript working, though that might be because the new files are never loaded
3. When needed, I could give my website in case you would want to check what might be the problem

Comment: You are experiencing this problem only from your computer or also in other devices? I mean, if you try to access this page from, for example, your mobile phone, you also get the old files?

Comment: Do you use `cloudflare` ? If yes, try to purge cache from cloudflare dashboard.

Comment: @AlbertoMartinez Nope, I've tried it on 2 pc's, both experience the same problem

Comment: @RafaelHovsepyan No I'm not using cloudflare

Comment: its some form of serverside cache. Is this shared hosting? If so look for any cache settings in the panel. Twig can also be configured to cache templates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386925/how-reload-twig-cache-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server side Cache. Kindly check php.ini whether opcache expiry time is set for too long.

- Opcache can cache.
- Nginx web server cache.

Comment: I've found out how to delete the cache! The pages are now updating

Comment: No there was a place in my Silex project (I'm using the fabpot skeleton) where cache was saved. I deleted everything in those folders, and then it worked again!

Comment: Oh okay, When you say it didn't updated by Output. I just came to its Cache.. mostly server side too there is cache. If it was enabled for so long it could cause the same thing :)